# removing duplicates using loop

Tags: r

I want to use function to make string(list) of certain column in df.
It has many duplicates so I use this custom function:

```
remove_duplicates = function(df) {
    paste(unique(df[,1]), collapse = ' ')
}
```

First lets create an example:

```
#dfs with set.seed to make sure we all on the same page
set.seed(123)
df1=data.frame("colour"=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
                   ,"shade"=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
                   ,"value"=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

df2=data.frame("colour"=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
                   ,"shade"=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
                   ,"value"=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

df=data.frame("colour"=(c(rep("RED",10),rep("BLUE",10),rep("GREEN",10)))
                   ,"shade"=c(rep(c(rep("LIGHT",5),rep("DARK",5)),3))
                   ,"value"=runif(30,min=0,max=1))

#necessary list
list.df.names=c("df1","df2","df3")
```

Now whats is happening with single df:

```
df1[,1]
#output
 [1] RED   RED   RED   RED   RED   RED   RED   RED   RED   RED   BLUE  BLUE  BLUE  BLUE  BLUE  BLUE  BLUE 
[18] BLUE  BLUE  BLUE  GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN GREEN
```

And my desired result is (here for one df):

```
remove_duplicates(df1)
#output
[1] "RED BLUE GREEN"
```

Problem arises when I try to loop this function:

```
for (i in 1:length(list.df.names)) {
  remove_duplicates(list.df.names[i])
  }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
 Error in df[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include an example. If `df.list` is a list of dataframes then perhaps `dput( lapply (head(df.list) , head, 3))`. You should also explain what you when columns get shortened. Perhaps you just want the output from `lapply( df.list, unique)`

Comment: Does the function work when not in a loop? General code-writing advice: make sure a and b work on their own before testing a∘b.

Comment: I added reproducible example and desired output. However now I see there are different "types" of outputs when I use `df[,1]` and `remove_duplicates(df1)`. Hope that wont cause any troubles later.

Comment: The title is really misleading - although you are removing duplicates, the problem you have is a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works

```
for (i in 1:length(list.df.names)) {
  a <- remove_duplicates(eval(parse(text=list.df.names[i])))
  print(a)
}

#[1] "RED BLUE GREEN"
#[1] "RED BLUE GREEN"
#[1] "RED BLUE GREEN
```

In above, `parse(text)` converts the string in `text` to an expression. Then the `eval` evaluates this - so, you get the value of the object named in text.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. Could you explain exactly what you did there? And why I was getting error?

Comment: Pleasure,  mate. I've edited the answer to include some explanation. Hope that's bit more clear now.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. When i pushed my work further I realised there is a small issue in part of my code. Objects created by remove_duplicates have `length` equal to `1`, not the actual length. For example your approach create vector looking like this: `"A B C"` when what I need is `"A" "B" "C"` (notice quotation marks). Could you provide me feedback on that?

Comment: For that, you need to change the `remove_duplicates` function to `remove_duplicates = function(df) {
  unique(df[,1])
}`